# Where can I find the cusom app from an installed package in Eclipse?

Tags: managed-package, eclipse, app

I have Custom App from a Managed Package which I need to include in my package.xml. However, I am unable to find it in Eclipse. I already looked in applications folder and even tried searching for the App Name but, still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click on the project name.
2. Click "Properties"
3. The project properties popup comes up.
4. On the left ruler open the "Force.com" folder.
5. Click On "Project Content"
6. on the right pane click "Add/Remove" button.
7. Select the component that you would like - app